# Can AWS Glue connect to a Data Store (RDS) that is hosted in VPC with dedicated Tenancy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I'm trying to connect a glue to and RDS(Postgres) that is sitting in a VPC (This VPC is created with Dedicated Tenancy for security reasons). I have tried every way possible but Glue keep throwing error message that It doesn't support Dedicated Tenancy VPC (See screen shot). Is this he case or am I missing something here. I have tried VPC endpoint, Internet Gateway, Self-referencing SG but nothing seemed to have a successful connection between Glue and this RDS. Any help is really appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Isn't error message clear? Its not supported with glue.

Comment: Yes, but there is nothing in the documentation that supports that. I know for Lambda is the same case and in the documentation you can see it . But for glue I dont see anything mentioning that.